# Calling glTranslatef with current coordinates is moving objects at a constant speed(OpenGL ES 1.1)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I've currently been following a book detailing OpenGL ES 1.1 on android. In one example, we've been moving many different textured objects across the screen. When we used glTranslatef() to move the objects, I expected we would use a constant amount(eg, 50 so that the object had the same speed). However, what we do is take the current coordinates of the object(which is constantly being incremented by 50). Shouldn't that make the object faster? When coordinates are (5,5), we are moving by 5 pixels in each axis. When that becomes (55,55), the object will be moving  55 pixels on each axis. However, I do not see a increase in speed at all as time goes on. Why is this?

```
            gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glOrthof(0, 320, 0, 480, 1, -1);

            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            bobTexture.bind();

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BOBS; i ++){
                gl.glLoadIdentity();
                gl.glTranslatef(bobs[i].x, bobs[i].y, 0);
                gl.glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1);
                gl.glScalef(2, 0.5f, 0);
                bobModel.draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
            }
```

Bob.java

```
    public float x, y;
    float dirX, dirY;

    public Bob() {
        x = rand.nextFloat() * 320;
        y = rand.nextFloat() * 480;
        dirX = 50;
        dirY = 50;
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        x = x + dirX * deltaTime;
        y = y + dirY * deltaTime;

        if (x < 0) {
            dirX = -dirX;
            x = 0;
        }

        if (x > 320) {
            dirX = -dirX;
            x = 320;
        }

        if (y < 0) {
            dirY = -dirY;
            y = 0;
        }

        if (y > 480) {
            dirY = -dirY;
            y = 480;
        }
    }
```

The full code is availble at https://github.com/Apress/beg-android-games-3ed/tree/master/ch07-gl-basics/Ch07/app/src/main/java/com/badlogic/androidgames, in packages gl and glbasics, classes Bob, BobTest, and Vertices.

Comment: *"However, what we do is take the current coordinates of the object"* - No, why? The coordinates are incremented by `dirX * deltaTime` and  `dirY * deltaTime` in every frame. That's a constant speed. The model vie matrix is _cleared_ in every frame (`gl.glLoadIdentity();`) and the current position is set by (`glTranslatef`).

Comment: Ohhh, thank you so much! I just realized that glLoadIdentity() sets us back to the origin(bottom left corner) so we're updating from there! So for example, the random gen was 0 and it got incremented by 50 (since 1 second passed in deltatime), so now the coords of the bob are (50,50). Starting from the origin, openGL sets the coordinates of the shape drawn after to be that many coordinates away... then when bob is (100,100), we go to the origin again, and set the shape's coordinates to be moved (100,100) from the origin. Thanks!